# relation between chmod and sudo on an executable file

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

What is the relationship between `chmod` and `sudo` on an executable file for a user?

Are the cases that "a user needs sudo to run an executable" the same as the cases that "chmod hasn't set the execution mode bit for the user"?

Are the cases that "a user doesn't need sudo to run an executable" the same as the cases that "chmod has set the execution mode bit for the user"?

More specifically,

1. For an executable file, If `chmod` doesn't set its execution
   permission for a user, must that user run the executable with `sudo` or `su`?
2. if `chmod` sets its execution permission for a user, does
   that mean that the user can run the executable without `sudo` or `su`?
3. How do you make an executable runnable only with `sudo` or `su` by a given user?
4. Conversely, if  a user can run an executable only with `sudo` or `su`,
   does that mean `chmod` hasn't set execution permission of the executable file for the
   user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the terminology. `chmod` is a program (and a system call) which alows changing permission bits of a file in a filesystem. `sudo` is a special program that allows running other programs with different credentials (typically with elevated privileges, most usually those of the root user). `su` is similar but less (read "not") configurable than `sudo` - most importantly it requires authenticates users based on the knowledge of the root password (which is security-wise rather appalling).

The executable bit says whether the contents of a file may be loaded into the memory and run (it doesn't say anything about whether it makes sense - you can set the executable bit of a JPEG image and watch it fail spectacularly when you try to run it).

Now for the questions:

1. the permissions are evaluated once the executable is being loaded. In the case of `su` and `sudo` this happens with the effective IDs (user and group - the credentials used in privilege evaluation - see the `credentials(7)` man page) of the target user. Hence if the target user is allowed to execute the file it is executed.
2. As mentioned above: when the executable bit is set for the effective UID or GID, then it can be executed. Otherwise not.
3. Generally, you don't. If you want, you can mark it as executable only for certain IDs and then prepare the `sudo` configuration so that it allows certain users to run that binary with the credentials of one of those that have executable rights on the file.
4. No. It usually does not make much sense to prevent users from running programs that require special privileges - programs should handle lack of those (gracefully if possible). Some programs even have only some functionality that doesn't require special rights but offer more when run with special privileges - one example is `route`: unprivileged users may use it to display kernel routing tables, while administrators can also change those.

Comment: Thanks. Are the cases that "a user needs sudo to run an executable" the same as the cases that "chmod hasn't set the execution mode bit for the user"? Are the cases that "a user doesn't need sudo to run an executable" the same as the cases that "chmod has set the execution mode bit for the user"?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `su` allows you to assume the identity of another user (i.e., run programs with different credentials). Unlike `sudo`, it requires the password of *the user whose identity you are assuming*; by default, this is “root”.

Comment: @Tim no and no. If a program doesn't have any executable bits (there are three - for the user, group and everybody else) even root can't run it. For the second question it's even more complex, but if you read the answer and the `credentials` man page again and think it through you'll find out why. At least point 4. of the answer should give you one reason why the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

This may be splitting hairs, but: to execute a file,
you must have execute permission to the file
*and all the directories you navigate to get to the file*. 
So, if Tom has a program (`do_interesting_stuff`) in his home directory (`/home/tom`),
and the directory is protected 700 (no access for anyone but owner)
but the file is protected 755 (read and execute permission for everybody),
you still ***will not*** be able to run `/home/tom/do_interesting_stuff` “as yourself” –
you will need to become root (or “become tom”)
with `sudo` or `su` to be able to execute that file.

And of course the same thing would be true
if you wanted to read a file (`interesting_stuff.txt`) in Tom’s home directory,
in the sense that you would need read access to the file
*and* execute permission on the directory.